# Problem in creating .desktop file, CentOS

Tags: java, centos, rpm

Hi I have created XYZ.desktop file. And the code for that desktop file is given below

### XYZ.desktop

```
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XYZ
GenericName=Generic Piece Of Software
Exec=startXYZ
Icon=/usr/local/XYZ/XYZ.png
#Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name[en_US]=XYZ
```

### startXYZ

```
#!/bin/sh
sh "/usr/local/XYZ/Installer"
```

If I run the start startXYZ file using  then it launches application but If I double click on .desktop file it doesnot open the application. The same file worked fine in Fedora but not working in CentOS. There is no file missing.

Can anyone please guide me what may be the problem for launching .desktop file

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Why have you tagged this with "java* and "rpm"??

Comment: .desktop file comes under rpm package manager and my application is in java swing

Answer (score 1):

Is `startXYZ` located in your `$path`?

Do you have `[Desktop Entry]` at the top of `XYZ.desktop`?

Comment: Just as a side note, remember that "[Desktop Entry]" is actually mandatory.